# Testng Report in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

How capture the testng report in runtime in eclipse, if it is possible then how..?

Runtime Testng report need to capture

In Testng supports runtime report capturing...?

Please tell me the step how we can capture the report

Answer (score 0):

We follow this approach:

1. We maintain 2 html reports. One is suite report that is to list down all the available test cases. Another is test case report used for each and every test cases. Every test case will have a report file in this format that has all the actions that are made with screenshots.
2. Use wrapper methods for every Selenium methods like click(), sendKeys() etc.
   So, instead of calling:
   `driver.findElement(byVar).click()`
   We call it like:
   `click(byVar,"Variable name");`
   This click method will have code to manipulate the html report that we create for every test case.
   We log this step in the report with this step name.

In @BeforeMethod, we create the test case's report. In @AfterMethod, we close that file and decide the pass/fail status in suite html file. Its too huge to explain everything here, bro. Hope this gives you a bit clarity.